# Select * from Birey b where not exists (select 1 from SınavOgrenci s where s.OgrenciId = b.Id ) join

Tags: mysql, sql

How is this done using join?
error message

```
select 
    * 
from Birey b 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from SınavOgrenci s 
    where s.OgrenciId = b.Id 
)
```

Comment: How to do it using join

Comment: What error message you get ? This seems valid SQL Statement.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your code is a `LEFT JOIN` of `Birey` to `SınavOgrenci` with a `WHERE` clause that filters out all the matching rows:

```
select b.* 
from Birey b left join SınavOgrenci s 
on s.OgrenciId = b.Id 
where s.OgrenciId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

What error message?

```
select *
from Birey b
left join SınavOgrenci s on s.OgrenciId = b.Id
where s.OgrenciId is null
```

(assuming Birey.Id can't be null)

But why not just continue to use not exists.